# How to inject a Provider using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I want to inject a `Provider<T>`, in something like this:

```
class Work {
   Provider<Tool> provider;
   @Inject
   Work (Provider<Tool> provider) { this.provider = provider; }
}
```

My `Module` looks something like this:

```
protected void configure () {
   bind (Tool.class).to(MyTool.class);
   // Q: How do I bind this:
   bind (new TypeLiteral<Provider<Tool>> {}).to (????);
   // A: Turns out deleting these last 3 lines makes everything just right.
}
```

I want to inject a `Provider<T>` because `Work` class needs to create more `Tool` objects and work with them. Also, I'm not sure there really needs to be a binding for `TypeLiteral<Provider<Tool>>` but I think it's closest approach for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just not binding it? I'd *expect* Guice to just build you a provider which resolves the non-provider binding each time.

From ["Injecting Providers"](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders):

> For every binding, annotated or not, the injector has a built-in binding for its provider.

So I *think* that just binding `Tool` will be enough. It's at least worth a try :) (I'd love to sound more confident, but I don't have as much Guice-fu as I'd like...)

Comment: You are right, I haven't seen that part (now I feel silly for not RTFM). And I can confirm it works ;). Thanks

Comment: Jon Skeet's right. Another way to put that is that binding a class creates a default provider internal to Guice which will get injected into any request for the provider of that class.